# "Be" VS "Is" --- in this context

Tags: grammar, verbs

> Let X **be** the age of John.
>
> Let X **is** the age of John.

Explain the difference and use of "be" form.

Answer (score 3):

*Let* is a catenating verb requiring an infinitival complement.

> Let him **go**.
>   Let him **speak** his mind.
>   Let X **be** the age of John.

*Let X **is*** is entirely ungrammatical.